# PC/Desktop IM Client that Supports GIFs via GIPHY?

Tags: chat, gif

I'm looking for an IM/chat client that will work on Windows which can connect to multiple services and meets the following criteria:

- Allows to add accounts from other services (e.g. Facebook,
  GoogleTalk, IRC)
- Allows user to search for GIFs from GIF repo (i.e.
  GIPHY) within client and allows them to send to target destination
- Allows for service-specific emojis or smileys (i.e. FB, Yahoo!)
- Client is not bloatware and comes with minimalist features supporting
  the above
- Software/Project is open-source or reasonably trustworthy
- Software/Project is free or maintains free version with limited
  feature set

I had tested Pidgin just yesterday and liked what I could enable through the client except for its apparent lacking ability to send GIFs via a built-in extension or feature. My reason for wanting this is not solely tied to FB but mainly my keyboard of choice on my Android device--which comes with native GIF support via GIPHY.

*Desired Platform Compatibility:*
**Windows 10 Pro 64-bit v. 1803**